# How do I save variables from a batch file then load them to use them?

Tags: batch-file

I'm a pretty inexperienced coder and I love batch because its one of the more straight forward coding languages but I want to save multiple variables to a txt file or other format then "load" those same variables to the batch file not to type so the player can see but so that I can use it

This is what I have so far for loading:

```
:nick
cls
color 02
set /p nick= Enter your nickname: 
if exist ((savegame%nick%.txt) goto load)
goto instructions

:load
for /f "blevel=" %%a in (savegame%nick%.txt) do set blevel=%%a&goto loadexist
for /f "mlevel=" %%a in (savegame%nick%.txt) do set mlevel=%%a&goto loadexist
for /f "alevel=" %%a in (savegame%nick%.txt) do set alevel=%%a&goto loadexist
```

this is what I have for saving:

```
:save
cls
echo Saving please wait...
(echo blevel=%blevel%)> savegame%nick%.txt
(echo mlevel=%mlevel%)>> savegame%nick%.txt
(echo alevel=%alevel%)>> savegame%nick%.txt
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
exit
```

Like I said I'm very inexperienced and my goal is to create a game please feel free to point out any flaws. In my game I have 3 characters Brutus, Mediana, and Achilles. `blevel`, `mlevel`, and `alevel` refers to the place in the game where you are and the character you chose to play as so you don't have to play the whole game to get to where you were.

As this is obviously still a work in progress I only have one instance where you can save and its in the first Brutus promt:

```
:brutus 1
set blevel=1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo You chose brutus good choice but are you sure this is who you want?
echo 1) go back and choose 
echo 2) continue
echo 0) save
set /p c=C:\

if "%c%" == 1 goto choose character
if "%c%" == 2 goto brutus 2
if "%c%" == 0 goto save
goto brutus 1
```

So when you get to a choice like this your respective level goes up. Every time I reopen the game it either closes cmd when I type the nickname I used to save the file or it doesn't work and skips over it like the file or the variables in it don't exist. My intention is to do this with all three characters at every crucial choice so in the end I will probably have at least 100 per character.

Comment: Write a bat file from your program with `set var=yourvar` on each line. Then you just `call` this batfile to set the variables in your program.

Comment: `for /f "blevel"`? `blevel` is not a valid option and will give you a syntax error which. See `for /?`. For debugging, don't start your batchfile with a doubleclick, open it manually in an open `cmd` window. This way, the window keeps open, so you  can read any errormessages.

Comment: White-spaces are not allowed in label names, so `:brutus 1` is invalid (only the `:brutus` portion will be used), so you need to replace the space by another character (e. g., `:brutus_1`) or dismiss it at all...

Answer (score 0):

your "save" logic is ok.

For loading, you need just a single line:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (savegame%nick%.txt) do set "%%i"
```

When you run it with `echo on`, you see that it processes every line and sets your variables.